# Drawing polygon using mouse click in Cesium?

Tags: cesium

I need to draw a polygon dynamically using my mouse. I can do this very easy in OpenLayers but I'm very new in Cesium and can't find any tutorials to do it.

Many examples only show how to create a polygon using hard coded geometries.

This is how to add a polygon using hard coded geometries:

```
var redPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Red polygon on surface',
    polygon : {
        hierarchy : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([-115.0, 37.0,
                                                        -115.0, 32.0,
                                                        -107.0, 33.0,
                                                        -102.0, 31.0,
                                                        -102.0, 35.0]),
        material : Cesium.Color.RED
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is a bit simple. If we give a callback function to the `hierarchy` attribute the entity starts to observe the given function return (the polygon geometry).

So my first try is to create a button or mouse click event to add a coordinate pair to an array and then pass a callback function to serve that array to the entity geometry.

Lets see:

```
var arrayOfCartesian = [];

function addMouseClickListener() {
    viewer.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        // Find a way to get the position.
        // ... var position = <SOME MAGIC>
        cartographic = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartesianToCartographic(position);
        arrayOfCartesian.push( cartographic );
    }, false);  
}

var getSelectorLocation = new Cesium.CallbackProperty( function() {
    return Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartographicArrayToCartesianArray( arrayOfCartesian );
}, false);


var entity = viewer.entities.add({
    polygon : {
          hierarchy : getSelectorLocation,
          outline : true,
          outlineColor : Cesium.Color.RED,
          outlineWidth : 9,
          perPositionHeight: true,
          material : Cesium.Color.BLUE.withAlpha(0.0),
    }
});
```

Now every time you click on the map you'll fire the `click` event that will add a new coordinate pair to the `arrayOfCartesian` array.

The `entity` will be watching the `arrayOfCartesian` array by the `getSelectorLocation` callback function and will update its geometry using some dark magic.

I know this is not a solid answer but it is the best I can do at this moment.

Comment: what does some<SOME MAGIC> here ?

Comment: How to get the position is not the scope.  You can find thousands examples around.  You can open a new question to it.

Comment: Semi-related, I was getting errors trying to use CallbackProperty similar to this but with an array and the resolution was here: https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium/issues/8135